# What is a "graph object"?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I typed the following on Mathematica:

> [image]

I am confused: How come those graphs are not connected? Trying to debug it, I tried to use other graph functions such as GraphDistanceMatrix and it yields:

> [image]

So it seems the problem is that those are not "graph objects". I also tried:

> [image]

But that also doesn't convert it to a graph object. I tried to look up the help but nothing relevant appeared.

Comment: `M` and `U` are *adjacency matrices*, and not graphs. You want to apply `AdjacencyGraph[]` to get something that has the head `Graph`.

Comment: In addition to what @J.M. said: A graph object is any expression where [`GraphQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphQ.html) returns `True`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`M` and `U` in your example are matrices, not graphs. You can use [`AdjacencyGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html) to create a graph from them.

---

The output of [`GraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot.html) is a [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) expression, not a [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) expression.

---

We use the term "graph expression" to denote the data structure that Mathematica uses to represent graphs.

A graph expression will always have [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) `Graph`.

[`GraphQ[g]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphQ.html) returns `True` if and only if `g` is a graph expression. Usually, we simply say that "`g` is a graph" (not a matrix, not a list of edges, not a picture showing a graph, but *a graph*).

---

Almost all functions whose name ends in `Q` always return either `True` or `False` in Mathematica.  Thus, `ConnectedGraphQ` will:

- return `True` for a connected graph
- return `False` for a non-connected graph
- return `False` (*without* an error message!) for anything that is not a graph